# Insert rows by AutoFill using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a macro which can insert a new row below the last row, containing the same formulas and formatting (not the values) as the rows above. If I do it by hand I would select an entire row and use the AutoFill feature, but this didn't work out when I try to implement it in my macro.

What I basically did is this:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim lRow As Long
Dim lRsp As Long
On Error Resume Next

Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
lRow = Selection.Row() - 1
lRsp = MsgBox("Insert New row above " & lRow & "?", _
    vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
If lRsp <> vbYes Then Exit Sub

Rows(lRow).Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(lRow, lRow + 1)

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

[Insert rows by AutoFill using VBA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vkfA.jpg)

Comment: `Range(lRow, lRow + 1)` -> `Range(lRow & ":" & lRow + 1)`.

Comment: Also get rid of the `On Error Resume Next`, that's just hiding all potential errors.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @BigBen. That's good to know.

This still doesn't solve the issue, since it is only copying the last row to the new row.

Comment: Perhaps use `Copy`, and `PasteSpecial`.

Comment: Have you formatting as a table?

Answer (score 0):

why not try to copy the last cell with formula and paste in the range of the new rows.

```
'Callback for btnRellenarFormulas onAction
Sub btnRellenarFormulas_OnClick()
    Sheets("YourSheet").Select ' the sheet you will add rows
    'Here add your rows, you current code just to add below will solve the column D problem
    Dim nRows As Double, nRowLastFormula As Double
'chose one and remove or comment the other one
    nRows = Range("CONFIG_NROWS_DATOS") 'This is a named range with formula counta, which counts the number of rows after add the new rows, in your case the column A
'or you can use the formula in code:
    nRows = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets(1).Range("A:A"))
'Remove one or comment
    nRowLastFormula = Range("CONFIG_NROWS_FORMULA")'this is a named range with formula counta, which will count the number of rows wiht fomula
'or you can use the formula in code:
'The counta in column D will be less than the countA column A, maybe you will need plus 1 to the nRowLastFormula value: nRowLastFormula=nRowLastFormula +1
    nRowLastFormula = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets(1).Range("D:D"))
    'Column A
    Range("A" & nRowLastFormula).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A" & nRowLastFormula + 1 & ":A" & nRows).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Good Luck